# Unable to understand the concept mentioned in http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/SuffixArrays

Tags: string, algorithm, search, suffix-array

Please explain:

> Suppose we have a suffix array corresponding to an n-character text and we want to find all occurrences in the text of an m-character pattern. Since the suffixes are ordered, the easiest solution is to do binary search for the first and last occurrences of the pattern (if any) using O(log n) comparisons.

I need to know how I can get *all occurrences of pattern after determining the first and last occurrence of pattern*.

Answer (score 1):

The text you quoted is slightly confusing, perhaps even misleading, in two ways:

1. It says it suffices to find the first and last occurrence of the pattern, but it should say, more precisely: the first and last occurrence of the pattern **in the suffix array**. That is not the same as the first and last occurrence in the underlying text.
2. It says you need O(log n) comparisons. This is only true if "comparison" refers to a *string comparison* of up to m characters. Since comparing up to m characters takes O(m) time, the number of computational steps (e.g. in the standard RAM model) is O(m*log n). It can be improved if auxiliary data structures are built and used, such as the LCP (longest-common-prefix) array.

Now, to answer your question: Taking (1.) above into account, you get all occurrences of the pattern easily **because the suffix array is sorted lexicographically**. This means the first occurrence is the lexicographically smallest, and the last occurrence is the lexicographically greatest. Hence, the remaining occurrences **must be in between** the first and the last.

**Example.** Consider the string `bcfabcabxbbcabcgdebcd`. Its suffix array (represented as starting positions of suffixes, counting from 0) is

```
[3, 12, 6, 9, 10, 4, 18, 0, 13, 7, 11, 5, 19, 1, 14, 20, 16, 17, 2, 15, 8]
```

which corresponds to the following list of suffixes:

```
3  : abcabxbbcabcgdebcd
12 : abcgdebcd
6  : abxbbcabcgdebcd
9  : bbcabcgdebcd
10 : bcabcgdebcd            <======= first occurrence of 'bc'
4  : bcabxbbcabcgdebcd
18 : bcd
0  : bcfabcabxbbcabcgdebcd
13 : bcgdebcd               <======= last occurrence of 'bc'
7  : bxbbcabcgdebcd
11 : cabcgdebcd
5  : cabxbbcabcgdebcd
19 : cd
1  : cfabcabxbbcabcgdebcd
14 : cgdebcd
20 : d
16 : debcd
17 : ebcd
2  : fabcabxbbcabcgdebcd
15 : gdebcd
8  : xbbcabcgdebcd
```

Suppose the pattern you are looking for is 'bc'. I have marked the first and last occurrences of that pattern in the suffix array. Because of the lexicographical sorting, all entries in between must start with 'bc' as well, and any entry starting with 'bc' must be somewhere in between. Therefore all suffixes starting with 'bc', i.e. all positions of occurrences of 'bc', must be between this first and last occurrence.

Expressed as position integers, the range we identified is

```
[10, 4, 18, 0, 13]
```

Hence positions 10, 4, 18, 0 and 13 mark occurrences of the pattern.

(Note that in practice the full string list of the suffixes is not used – only the integer position list.)